# javascript and php do not work together

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm writing the register page for my website.Here is my register page.Can anyone show me why it does not check whether The username is already in use or not.I don't know whether PHP and javascript can work together or not.

The html page is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>

</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript">
  function checkInput()
  {
   if(document.register.username.value=="")
   {
      alert("Fill in username");
      document.register.username.focus();
      return false;
    }else if(document.register.password.value==""){
      alert("Fill in your password");
      document.register.password.focus();
      return false;
}else {
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
include "connect.php";
$username=$_POST['username'];
$query="SELECT username FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $arr[]=$row['username'];    
}
if(in_array($username,$arr)){
    ?>
    alert("Username is already in use");// this part does not work!
    document.register.username.focus();
    return false;
<?php
}
}
?>
}
    }
  </script>

<form name="register" method="post" action="dangki.php" onsubmit="return checkInput();">
  <table width="289" height="185" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">register</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="83">Username</td>
      <td width="190"><input type="text" name="username" id="textfield" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="password" id="textfield2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Re-type Password</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="repassword" id="textfield3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit">    </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes and no. PHP and JS can work together, through Ajax. Not in the way you coded because PHP is processed server-side, all the php in the page will be processed and outputted as HTML before any JS can run. PHP will only run again when you submit or reload the page. Hence you either use Ajax checking for the username availability or do it all with PHP.

Comment: Does *every* code path in your `checkInput()` function return `false`?  Is your form even submitting?  If the form isn't actually submitting to the server, how do you expect the server-side PHP code to respond to it?

Comment: @David JS functions are default to return `true`, so if it doesn't get in any error path the form would be submitted (considering a valid function, of course).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: That is not correct, JS functions do not return anything by default. They will only return a specific value (including boolean true and boolean false) if you explicitly code your function to do so.

Comment: @Arjan [Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/eehJ9/4/). The submit `event` is not cancelled unless you `return false`, hence `true` is assumed for this case. Sorry for the bad wording.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté that appears to be the case. Submit is only canceled when you return boolean false. Still I think that readability improves when boolean true is returned if you want to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Not, Javascript and PHP do not "work together" in that way.  Javascript runs in your browser, PHP runs on the server before that. Therefore, you cannot use PHP for client side validation, only server side. For a first demonstration of this, just "view source" on what your page looks like to the browser.

You have to think of them separately. You have to have PHP just check what the form submits, and return a new page that indicates whether it was a valid/new username and allows the user to try again if needed.

You can sort of fake it with ajax, but even that is just sending a request to the server, which is run separately, and returns a result to the page, to be processed by a different function.  It would get more complicated that your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is evaluated on the server side. JavaScript is evaluated on the client side. That is to say: when a user makes a request to the server, the php is evaluated on the server, the resulting output is sent to the user, if there is javascript involved, it is evaluated on the client, after the php has evaluated.

This means that PHP can give messages to javascript, but javascript cannot send messages to php. In your code it looks like you want php to evaluate the user input that javascript is taking. This cannot be done because when the javascript is running, the php is already finished.

One way you could provide the functionality you want is to write php code to write the code for an array in javascript, containing all usernames. The javascript could then look through this array to tell the user if the username is taken. This has some flaws though, if you have a lot of users, you will be transmitting a lot of text to a new user. This may be a security problem too because everyone would be able to know all the user names of all the people registered with the site, there is also the potential for someone to load the page, type in their user name, wait a long time, have someone else create an account with their same name, and then the first person come back, submit the page, and then you will have two users with the same user name.

It may be easier, but less fun, to write the whole site in php first, and after it's all working, add the javascript to spruce up functionality.